# Replacing two adjacent thermostats with one

Tags: electrical, thermostat, baseboard, canada

My home has two adjacent thermostats, each one controls a single 1000W 240V baseboard heater. The heaters themselves are on opposite walls of the dining room. I’d like to replace both thermostats with a single smart Mysa thermostat. I’ve already done the replacement in every other room of the house but I’d rather not have two thermostats here, and I can’t fit two Mysas side by side within this space anyway.

What’s the best way to do this in this spot? I think I should be able to wire the loads in parallel to a single thermostat but I’m not sure on the best way to do the wiring. Should I take the load wires out of the top box and move them into the bottom one? Or run a new jumper from one box to the other?

Answer (score 2):

There are two different possibilities here:

- Same Circuit

If the heaters are currently on the same circuit (i.e., turning off one double-breaker turns off both heaters) then this is easy. If you can move the wires from one box to the other, great. If not, run cable from the *heater* side of one box to the other and pigtail the heater connections together to the heater/load side of the new thermostat.

- Different Circuits

In general 2 x 1000W heaters can easily fit on a single 240V circuit. 2000W / 240V = 8.33A. Multiple by 1.25 because continuous = 10.4A. Even a 15A circuit can handle that. However, it is possible that you have multiple heaters from different parts of the house on different circuits. For example, if you have 2 20A 240V circuits for heating then each can provide 3,840W of heat. If each of them currently handles 3,000W (3 x 1,000W) and each of the two relevant heaters is on a different circuit then moving one of them to the other circuit is not allowed (one circuit goes from 3,000W to 2,000W but the other goes from 3,000W to 4,000W > 3,840W).

So *if* they are currently on different circuits, you need to determine the total usage on each of the circuits to figure out if/how to rearrange things to make it work. It may be easy or it may involve moving heaters in other rooms between circuits.

Comment: They are on the same breaker, 30A